# converting for loop to while loop c#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm curious to know how you would convert the following into a while loop.  I know it doesn't make the most sense in this situation but I am working out of a student workbook and would like to see another example.  Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

```
int sides = 0; 
int number = 0; 
int total = 0; 

Random random = new Random(); 
Console.WriteLine("Choose the number of sides."); 
sides = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Choose number of dice.");
number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) 
{
   int die = random.Next(1, sides); 
   Console.WriteLine("You Rolled {0}", die.ToString());d
   total += die;
}

Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0}", total);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
while(i < number)
{
       int die = random.Next(1, sides); 
       Console.WriteLine("You Rolled {0}", die.ToString());
       total += die;
       i++
}
```

Comment: That was fast.  I was typing the "w" in `while` in my answer when your answer showed up

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert a `for-loop` to a `while-loop` if I understand correctly.

```
int currentNum = 0;
while (currentNum < number)
{
   int die = random.Next(1, sides);
   Console.WriteLine("You Rolled {0}", die.ToString());
   total += die;

   currentNum++;
}
```

Comment: There is an error in your code. There is a "d" alone at the end of the 5th line.